# Evolution not accepting my Hotmail password

Tags: password, email, evolution

I have been struggling for a while with Evolution not accepting my Hotmail account password for receiving emails. The sending of email is not a problem. I also have a Gmail account which works fine for both receiving and sending. The password is also definitely correct. 
I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with evolution v 3.10.4.

Upon starting Evolution, I get the following prompt:

[image: Password input dialog in Evolution]

I enter the correct password and it doesn't accept it and prompts me again:

[image: Password input dialog in Evolution showing "Password was incorrect" with filled password]

After the second or third attempt it shows the following error message:

[image: Error while fetching mail from example@hotmail.com. Cannot get POP summary.]

My settings are as follows:

[image: Server: pop3.live.com | Port: 995 | Encryption method: SSL on a dedicated port]

and

[image: Check for new messages every 10 minutes | Leave messages on server]

Comment: Why POP and not IMAP? :) Did you manually enable POP on your hotmail account? (it is disabled by default)

Comment: I set up evolution to use the pop protocol. I leave the emails on the server so they don't get deleted. Is there a way to change this to imap after I have set it up as pop? I think this would be preferable but don't know if it is possible.

Comment: It is downloading now after I went into hotmail through web browser and set option > mail > accounts > pop and imap. I changed it to device using pop, and don't allow device and apps delete emails. I also changed the server to: `pop-mail.outlook.com` in evolution. This resolves the issue but would much prefer if I could use imap if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dadexix86 I managed to fix it. I needed to open my hotmail account in a web browser and set **option > mail > accounts > pop and imap** to the following:

[image]

I also needed to change the settings in evolution Preference menu to use `imap-mail.outlook.com` server.